# Mediation Analysis with only repeated measures in R

Tags: r, statistics, repeat

I conducted a study where participants took part in a training to increase mindfulness and my results show that the training was indeed effective as there are significant differences between the timepoint of measurement.
I also acquired data on attentional capabilites (which also improved through the training) and would now like to know if increase in attentional skills mediate the improvements in mindfulness.

I worked with path models before however I am usnure how to apply them to my data because I don´t really have an independent variable X.
I have the mindfulness scors for T1 and T2 and the attention scores (mediator) for T1 and T2 (T1 is before the Training and T2 is after).

How could I test paths here to obtain values for direct and indirect effect?

Comment: this is DataOverflow question- not to StackOverflow- he we help with coding- not a theoretical framework